# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'doTimeout'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to debug someone's code (fun fun!), the code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#userinput").keyup(function(){
   jQuery(this).doTimeout('text-type', 250, function(){
      jQuery('#output').empty();
      var input = $(this).val();
      if (input.length > 0) {
        getUsers(input);
      } else {
        jQuery('#output').attr('size', 1);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

The included doTimeout script in the parent document is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/raw/master/jquery.ba-dotimeout.min.js"></script>
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'doTimeout'

(In the magic chrome inspector)

I've been grappling with this for a while and not had any luck. My JS knowledge isn't great so I was hoping it was something rather obvious that I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Is that the actual jQuery lib?

Comment: The github copy must have changed and removed the method.

Comment: Well you can see the github copy by following the link, theres an original in the repo, function is still there. @tymeJV, not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: Never reference directly github packages; jsfiddle says "Github is not a CDN, using it as such will cause issues with loading the file" good advice!

Comment: is doTimeout synonymous with setTimeout?

Answer (score 3):

Referencing the script directly from Github may not work due to raw.github.com sending `text/plain` mime type headers instead of `text/javascript`, try using a local copy. You'll likely get better performance that way too.

If Chrome refuses to run the script due to the mime type issue, then it won't add the `doTimeout` method to jQuery objects, resulting in this error.